# Springboot - Ambiguous mapping found - While controllers are defined with different paths

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There are 2 controller, each extend an interface which is not defined as controller. Now, I have defined different paths for each, but still getting ambiguous mapping found error.

Controller1

```
@RestController("/admin")
public final class AdminController implements BaseUserController {

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public User create(@RequestBody final User user) throws Exception {
    return null;
}
}
```

Controller2

```
@RestController("/user")
public final class ConsumerController implements BaseUserController {

@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public User create(@RequestBody final User user) throws Exception {
    return null;
}
}
```

And this is the error I am getting

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerMapping' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/user' method 
usermanager.controller.ConsumerController#create(User)
to {POST []}: There is already '/admin' bean method
usermanager.controller.AdminController#create(User) mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:123)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    ... 92 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous mapping. Cannot map '/user' method 
usermanager.controller.ConsumerController#create(User)
to {POST []}: There is already '/admin' bean method
usermanager.controller.AdminController#create(User) mapped.
```

I am not sure why the two methods are mapping to same path while I have already defined the paths for controllers. What did I miss?

Comment: You are defining the name of the beans with the `@RestController` Annotation. Specifiy the path in your PostMappings. Or  do as @Setu wrote

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using `@RestController` annotation's `value` field as a url mapping which is not correct.

```
@RestController("/admin")
```

and

```
@RestController("/user")
```

are creating two controller bean with component/bean names `/admin` and `/user`. This means the `create` method from both class are trying to map to same root url `/`. If you want all methods in a controller class to be mapped to specific url then you need to use `@RequestMapping` annotation along with `@RestController`. Change it to below;

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
```

and

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont configure the endpoint in `@RestController("/user")` annotation itself.
At a class level, the endpoints should be configured to @RequestMapping annotation like
`@RequestMapping("/user")` same way for `"/admin"` end point.

Do try and let know if the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

Specify the path in @RequestMapping annotation or you can also specify the path in @PostMapping annotations which are at method level.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
```

or

```
@RestController
public final class AdminController implements BaseUserController {

@PostMapping("/admin")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public User create(@RequestBody final User user) throws Exception {
    return null;
}
}
```